# Enter value in a webform and push the return key with applescript

Tags: applescript

I want to enter a value on a webform and then push enter as there is no button to click on the page

I cannot provide any URL as it is a private web tool.

The search box is a simple webform where I enter a value and then push enter to charge the results.

I already wrote the part of the script adding the value in the box, no problem with that. My issue is to find a way for the keystroke return work on the page.

```
set theValue to "1111111"

to inputByID(theId, theValue)

    tell application "Safari"

        do JavaScript "document.getElementById('" & theId & "').value = '" & theValue & "'" in document 1

    end tell

end inputByID

inputByID("TextField", theValue)
```

So this works perfectly. I then tried to add a `Keystroke return` every where I could imagine and I always get the same error message:

```
Result:
error "Safari got an error: Can’t get keystroke \"
\"." number -1728 from keystroke "
"
```

I'm not sure if there is anything else to do here. Looking at the Page Source I cannot find any relevant information, that's why I really wanted to go through this road.

Comment: When you look at the page source, is this text input contained within a form element? The javascript approach would be to find the input's form and use form.submit(), rather than trying to simulate a key event.

Comment: thank you. I'll try to see if I can figure it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use a *keystroke* in your scenario, two conditions must exist.

- **Safari** needs to be frontmost and active.
- The cursor must be in a text field that can receive input.

The **AppleScript** *code* for that would be:

```
tell application "Safari" to activate
delay 0.5
tell application "System Events" to keystroke return
```

With **System Events**, for `return`, you can also use:

```
tell application "System Events" to key code 36
```

Note that the `delay` *commands* allow time for the app to be frontmost and active before the *keystroke* is sent. Adjust as/if necessary.

Comment: thank you! I already tried the system event solution but it wouldn't work, it would actually add the keystroke inside the script editor (as it was the last window active). The Safari code works perfectly. I tried without the delay and it wouldn't work. Thanks for the tip!!